# Обособление частицы "вот"

Tags: частица

*- Ааааа, вот в чём дело!*

Отделяется ли частица "вот" запятой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В большом толковом словаре:
[ВОТ, *частица*](https://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82&all=x&lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x)
**3.** (*с частицами и местоим. в восклиц. предл.*). Употребляется **для усиления** восхищения, удивления, недоумения, разочарования, пренебрежения и т. п.
*Вот это новость! Вот так история! Вот оно что! Вот оно как! Вот это да!*

Запятая после "вот" не требуется:
**А-а-а, вот в чём дело!** ([Междометие "а"](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B0) лучше оформить с дефисом.)
[Ага, вот в чем дело-то!](https://glosum.ru/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%90%D0%B3%D0%B0) (В словаре Ожегова.)